# How to update particular variable of particular data in List<Map<String,dynamic>> in firebase using flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I have customer collection inside I have list of merchant data like

```
{
  'customer':'xyz',
  'contactNumber':'999999999',
  'merchantMap':[
       {
        'merchantName':'abx',
        'merchantId':'dsdfsbdmmm'
       },
       {'merchantName':'abx',
        'merchantId':'dsdfsbdmmm'
       }
  ]
}
```

Here inside merchantMap I want to update his name by checking his merchantId.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: could you include a sample of merchantMap too?

Comment: updated the code please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume your customer data is this:

```
var customerData = {
    'customer': 'xyz',
    'contactNumber': '999999999',
    'merchantMap': [
      {'merchantName': 'abx', 'merchantId': '12'},
      {'merchantName': 'abx', 'merchantId': '23'}
    ]
  };
```

and your specific id is this:

```
String selectedId = "23";
```

you can do this to change the item that contains that id:

```
var newMerchantMap =
    (customerData["merchantMap"] as List<Map<String, dynamic>>)
        .map((e) => e['merchantId'] == selectedId
            ? {'merchantName': 'newNAme', 'merchantId': e["merchantId"]}
            : e)
        .toList();

customerData['merchantMap'] = newMerchantMap;
```

result :

```
{
   customer: xyz,
   contactNumber: 999999999, 
   merchantMap: [
       {merchantName: abx, merchantId: 12},
       {merchantName: newNAme, merchantId: 23}
   ]
 }
```

Comment: @JaganBadiyar was it what you want?

Comment: Yex! exactly. Thank you so much!